# Use jQuery method on object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to use a jQuery function on a property of my js object, but it's giving me an error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined"`. Here is some sample code:

```
var foo = {
    bar: $('#element'),
    baz: this.bar.find('#childelement'), // <- jQuery .find() not working
    hideBaz: function() {
        this.baz.hide();
    }
}
```

Not really sure what to do here, any help would be great

Comment: Could you share the full source code, so we can reproduce the same problem? That way we can provide better answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use jQuery you need to use namespace provided by jQuery. ie - either jQuery or $ which are given with jQuery. You can also create your own namespace by using jQuery.noConflict().

If you use them then only jQuery will know you are trying to access its methods with their objects. Something like $(this) or $("yourselector").

So with the above, you can use

```
var foo = {
    bar: $('#selector'),
    baz: $(this).bar.find('#childSelector'), 
    hideBaz: function() {
        this.baz.hide();
    }
 }
```

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning  :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to enable jquery functionalities, you must use `$(this)` rather than just `this`. Without using `$(this)`, you will not be able to use any jquery on that object.

Answer (score 2):

you should wrap `this` in jquery :

```
var foo = {
    bar: $('#element'),
    baz: $(this).bar.find('#childelement'), 
    hideBaz: function() {
        this.baz.hide();
    }
}
```